# Prevent scrollbar with MarginLeft style change?

Tags: javascript, css

I have a big div with lots of items that I have moving to marginLeft='120%' on an event. I used overflow:hidden to keep it from showing a horizontal scrollbar. But the webpage vertical scrollbar length gets bigger when it moves to the right. I want the div to disappear off the screen(I have it HTML5 transitioning when it does that) but not affect the rest of the page. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: This has nothing to do with code style, as far as I can tell.

Comment: have you set the width of the transitioning element? Sounds like it is growing in height as the width compresses

Comment: The code, the whole code and nothing but the code, so help me code!

Comment: First of all, saying `I have a big div` is really unnecessary... Show off!

Answer (score 0):

The content is not actually moving to the right because the container isn't wide enough so the default action is to drop the content to the next line, hence the vertical scroll.

Try adding another `div` within the wrapping `div` with a large width, that way the content will have enough room to actually move to the right.

```
<div id="wrapper">
    <div id="inner">
        <div id="content"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS...

```
#wrapper {
    overflow: hidden;
}
#inner {
    width: 9000px;
}
```

Comment: I was getting a big wide horizontal layout this way

Comment: @Dave Set the width of #wrapper to however wide your layout needs to be. Nothing inside will show beyond that width since overflow:hidden is set. However the #content will be able to move to the right since #inner allows it 9000px of space to move within.

Comment: @Dave look at this carousel code. http://jsfiddle.net/wdm954/VFwLT/5/ - May help to see it in action. Basically it's a horizontal row of DIVs that slide around in the `overflow:hidden` DIV